# How to fetch Big Dataset from Twitter?

Tags: twitter, bigdata

For my database project,  I need to extract more than 50gb of data from Twitter. For this purpose, I've used the following code to connect to Twitter's stream. I used python and twitter library. Here is the code:

```
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json


from twitter import Twitter, OAuth, TwitterHTTPError, TwitterStream


ACCESS_TOKEN = "<my-token>"
ACCESS_SECRET = "my-secret"
CONSUMER_KEY = "my-key"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "my-key-secret"

oauth = OAuth(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)


twitter_stream = TwitterStream(auth=oauth)


iterator = twitter_stream.statuses.sample()


for tweet in iterator:
    print json.dumps(tweet)
```

But with this code, it can only generate around 750kb of data. Then it shows that `the connection is timed out.`  Is there any way to generate big data (like 50gb or more) by changing the code a bit without the connection being timed out?

And also how can I save those big data? (Is it possible that I found those data, somehow manage to store all the data in `json`  format and uploaded those data to cloud like google drive? If then kindly tell me.

Comment: Use Apache Flume

Comment: It says it works with HADOOP DB. But my DB is MongoDB